# Using in-memory database

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am having a problem using the in-memory database. I have created a new context with options to use an in-memory database but when I run my test dbProduct that is taken from the repo returns me a product that is on my applicaton's database instead of the in-memory database.

```
public class ProductServiceTests
    {
        private IRepository repo;
        private ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase("SportAreteMemoryDb")
                .Options;

            applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(contextOptions);

            applicationDbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            applicationDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task Test_AddProductAsync()
        {
            var repo = new Repository(applicationDbContext);

            IProductService productService = new ProductService(repo);

            await productService.AddProductAsync(new AddProductViewModel()
            {
                Model = "added product model",
                Description = "added product description",
                Size = "added product size",
                Colour = "added product colour",
                Price = 100M,
                CategoryId = 1,
                BrandId = 1,
                ImageData = "added product image link"
            });

            await repo.SaveChangesAsync();

            var dbProduct = await repo.GetByIdAsync<Product>(1);

            Assert.That(dbProduct.Description, Is.EqualTo("added product description"));

        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            applicationDbContext.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I have tried making it from scratch again but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem was. I am applying some configurations in OnModelCreating of my ApplicationDbContext that's why the first element is not what I expected to be.